# Ensuring Kafka consumer registers to an unassigned partition where consumers are running on multiple machines

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a use case where I want to assign a consumer to a partition, and have no other consumer consume that partition, I know this sounds easy with using a consumer group and using the subscribe method, but what I want eventually is that no rebalance happens if one of the consumer goes down. The other challenge is that these consumers will be running on multiple machines.

Let me give the complete scenario:

I have a topic `T` and `T` has 4 partitions. Now, there are two machines `M1` and `M2` each running two threads that consume from the 4 partitions, now I can assign each partition using the `assign` function in KAFKA.

**Challenges**
When the consumers are brought up I don't want to hard code the partition assignment in code, instead I use the `KafkaAdminClient` to find information about the topic and the consumer group to which these consumers belong, and programmatically find out which partition is assigned and which is not, this is very hard in a multi-machine mode, because the application running on both machine queries for the same consumer group and gets the same information, now say machine `M1` assigns partition 0 to thread0 and by that time machine `M2` also assigns the partition 0 to thread0, I have a problem both threads are consuming data from the same partition. This is the scenario that I fail to address. Below is some `KafkaAdminClient` code that I use to gather information about the consumer group and topic. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaFuture;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartitionInfo;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class KafkaConsumerAdmin {
    private final AdminClient adminClient;

    public KafkaConsumerAdmin(Properties adminProperties) {
        this.adminClient = AdminClient.create(adminProperties);
    }

    public List<TopicPartitionInfo> getTopicPartitionInfo(String topicName)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        DescribeTopicsResult describeTopicsResult = this.adminClient.describeTopics(
                Collections.singletonList(topicName)
        );
        KafkaFuture<Map<String, TopicDescription>> futureOfDescribeTopicResult = describeTopicsResult.all();
        Map<String, TopicDescription> topicDescriptionMap = futureOfDescribeTopicResult.get();
        TopicDescription topicDescription = topicDescriptionMap.get(topicName);
        return topicDescription.partitions();
    }

    public ConsumerGroupDescription getConsumerGroupInfo(String consumerGroupID)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        DescribeConsumerGroupsResult describeConsumerGroupsResult =
                this.adminClient.describeConsumerGroups(Collections.singletonList(consumerGroupID));
        KafkaFuture<Map<String, ConsumerGroupDescription>> futureOfDescribeConsumerGroupsResult =
                describeConsumerGroupsResult.all();
        Map<String, ConsumerGroupDescription> consumerGroupDescriptionMap = futureOfDescribeConsumerGroupsResult.get();
        return consumerGroupDescriptionMap.get(consumerGroupID);
    }

    public Map<String, Set<TopicPartition>> getConsumerGroupMemberInfo(ConsumerGroupDescription consumerGroupDescription) {
        Map<String, Set<TopicPartition>> memberToTopicPartitionMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (MemberDescription memberDescription : consumerGroupDescription.members()) {
            MemberAssignment memberAssignment = memberDescription.assignment();
            Set<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = memberAssignment.topicPartitions();
            memberToTopicPartitionMap.put(memberDescription.consumerId(), topicPartitions);
        }
        return memberToTopicPartitionMap;
    }

    public List<Integer> getAvailablePartitions(List<TopicPartitionInfo> topicPartitionInfoList,
                                                Map<String, Set<TopicPartition>> memberToTopicPartitionMap) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> partitionToMemberMap = new HashMap<>();
        topicPartitionInfoList.forEach(x -> partitionToMemberMap.put(x.partition(), new LinkedList<>()));
        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<TopicPartition>> entry : memberToTopicPartitionMap.entrySet()) {
            String memberID = entry.getKey();
            for (TopicPartition topicPartition : entry.getValue()) {
                partitionToMemberMap.get(topicPartition.partition()).add(memberID);
            }
        }
        return partitionToMemberMap.entrySet().stream().
                filter(x -> x.getValue().isEmpty()).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    Map<TopicPartition, Long> getConsumerGroupOffsetInfo(String consumerGroupID)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult listConsumerGroupOffsetsResult =
                this.adminClient.listConsumerGroupOffsets(consumerGroupID);
        KafkaFuture<Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata>> futureOfConsumerGroupOffsetResult =
                listConsumerGroupOffsetsResult.partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata();
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> consumerGroupOffsetInfo = futureOfConsumerGroupOffsetResult.get();
        return consumerGroupOffsetInfo.entrySet().stream().
                collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, x -> x.getValue().offset()));
    }
}
```

Comment: "*no rebalance happens if one of the consumer goes down*" -- So, you *want* to have idle consumer tasks and unconsumed partitions?

Comment: Yes an unconsumed partition is fine because its very critical that each consumer reads from only one partition to ensure ACID properties when it writes to different nosql based storages.

Comment: It's not clear if you're going to be writing a consumer manually to accomplish that, or using Kafka Connect database sinks, but once you're dependent on an external system, delivery guarantees become less clear. I'm under the impression that the producer isn't even ACID compliant, so any consumer wouldn't be able adhere to it either. In general, though, manually specification of partitions, and catching the appropriate errors in a poll loop, followed by manual offset commits would be the only way I know of

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand what u r saying clearly, my contention is not that the consumer will not adhere tp ACID properties, what I want is to assign partitions automatically by choosing which partitions are not being consumed by consumers in a specific group, had i been dealing where all consumers would be running on the same machine it would have been easy, but since the consumers could be running on `n` different machines its not an easy task to figure out which partitions are available and which are being consumed. Would really appreciate if you have some idea

Comment: All I can say here is that we run Kafka Connect worker tasks on up to 15 machines, writing to various other places such as Elasticsearch, SQL databases, Mongo, Cassandra, etc, and it seems to work fine, even in the event of rebalances. We don't manually specify partition assignment here, only the number of tasks for a Connector